# Javascript events odd behavior, removeEventListener not working

Tags: javascript, function, events

I am trying to stop an event from being called multiple times by removing the event listener when I am done with it. (I need to be able to call these functions multiple times)

However, my current solution does not seem to remove the event listener from the "imageEvilRace", because when I call these functions a second time, "killRacer" ends up "killing" the same element that was the target the first time, as well as the new target. (killRacer deletes the same image that it targeted the first time when it should have no reference to that first image the second time it is called)

Here are the relevant functions reduced to the parts that are important for my question.

```
function killRacer() {
    var listOfRaceImgs = getListOfRaceImages();

    var killRacerTimerID = setInterval(moveEvilRaceImage.bind(null, randomRacer), 40);

    imageEvilRace.addEventListener("stopKiller", stopMovingKillerImage.bind(null, killRacerTimerID, randomRacer));
}

function moveEvilRaceImage(imageToKill) {
    imageEvilRace.dispatchEvent(stopKillerEvent);
}

function stopMovingKillerImage(killRacerTimerID, randomRacer) {
    clearInterval(killRacerTimerID);
    randomRacer.style.display = "none";
    randomRacer.style.left = 0 + "px";
    imageEvilRace.src = explosionImageSource;
    imageEvilRace.removeEventListener("stopKiller", stopMovingKillerImage);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bound callback is `stopMovingKillerImage.bind(null, killRacerTimerID, randomRacer)` but you try to unbind `stopMovingKillerImage`. They're two different functions.

I would create a wrapper function to handle the storage of the correct function for a single-use event handler like this:

```
function bindOnce(object, event, callback) {
    var new_callback = function() {
        callback.apply(this, arguments);
        object.removeEventListener(event, new_callback)
    };

    object.addEventListener(event, new_callback);
}

bindOnce(imageEvilRace, "stopKiller", stopMovingKillerImage.bind(null, killRacerTimerID, randomRacer));
```